# EF 5.0 Code First adding new children to existing parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Overview:**
I am working on an MVC ASP.Net app using Code First and EF 5.0. I have two tables: Scripts and ScriptItems. A Script can have multiple ScriptItems. ScriptItems are hierarchical as well. ScriptItems can optionally belong to each other, however this relationship is only 1 level deep thankfully. This relationship is indicated by ScriptItem.ParentId.

**The problem:**
Creating a new Script entry with ScriptItems works just fine. The problem arises when I try to add ScriptItems to an existing Script. If I try to add ScriptItems that do NOT have a ParentId, everything works fine. As soon as I try to add ScriptItems that do have a ParentId, I receive a FK violation exception.

**Details:**

Script class:

```cs
public class Script
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProcessorId")]
    public Processor Processor { get; set; }
    public int ProcessorId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }

    public List<ScriptItem> Items { get; set; }
    public List<ScriptRun> Runs { get; set; }

    public Script()
    {
        Items = new List<ScriptItem>();
        Created = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

ScriptItem class: (Truncated for brevity)

```cs
 public class ScriptItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public ScriptItem Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public Script Script { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Script")]
    public int ScriptId { get; set; }
```

The function that adds script items:

```cs
private void addToScript(ScriptModel model, List<int> ids)
    {
        Script script = scriptRepository.GetScriptWithItems(model.ScriptId);
        List<History> historyItems = historyRespository.History.Where(h => ids.Contains(h.Id)).ToList();

        ScriptItem lastScriptItem = script.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.SortIndex).FirstOrDefault();
        int topSortIndex = lastScriptItem == null ? 0 : lastScriptItem.SortIndex;

        if (script != null)
        {
            List<ScriptItem> newItems = new List<ScriptItem>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<History, ScriptItem>();
            foreach (History h in historyItems)
            {
                ScriptItem scriptItem = new ScriptItem();
                Mapper.Map(h, scriptItem); //Populate new ScriptItem from History entry
                scriptItem.SortIndex = ++topSortIndex;
                scriptItem.ScriptId = model.ScriptId;
                scriptItem.Script = script;

                //Only add an entry if it is NOT the parent of another entry. Otherwise, EF will duplicate the Parent entries
                if (!historyItems.Any(his => his.ParentId == h.Id))
                    newItems.Add(scriptItem);    
            }
            scriptRepository.AddScriptItems(newItems);
        }
    }
```

And finally the scriptRepository.AddScripItems():

```cs
public void AddScriptItems(List<ScriptItem> items)
    {
        items.ForEach(item => context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Consider the scenario where I add two ScriptItems A and B to an existing script. A is the parent of B. When I run a SQL Server trace, I see that an attempt is made to insert the parent record A, but with a ScriptId of 0 hence the FK violation exception. No clue why ScriptId is 0. ScriptId is set properly on the ScriptItems, I verified this with the debugger.

I did not include the function that inserts new Scripts and Items, because it is very similar to the addToScript function above. And it works fine. But if someone wants to see it, I can add that too.

Someone smarter than me have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gert Arnold for pointing me in the right direction. The issue ultimately stemmed from how I was building my ScriptItems via AutoMapper. I cant explain what the exact issue is, but here is my revised working code in case anyone finds it useful.

```cs
private void addToScript(ScriptModel model, List<int> ids)
    {
        Script script = scriptRepository.GetScriptWithItems(model.ScriptId);
        List<History> historyItems = historyRespository.History.Where(h => ids.Contains(h.Id)).ToList();

        ScriptItem lastScriptItem = script.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.SortIndex).FirstOrDefault();
        int topSortIndex = lastScriptItem == null ? 0 : lastScriptItem.SortIndex;

        if (script != null)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<History, ScriptItem>();
            List<ScriptItem> Parents = new List<ScriptItem>();
            List<History> SourceParents = historyItems
                .Where(h => historyItems.Any(h2 => h2.ParentId == h.Id)).ToList();

            SourceParents.Each(h =>
            {
                ScriptItem parent = new ScriptItem();
                Mapper.Map(h, parent);
                parent.Script = script;
                Parents.Add(parent);
            });

            historyItems.Except(SourceParents).Each(h =>
            {
                ScriptItem child = new ScriptItem();
                Mapper.Map(h, child);
                child.Script = script;
                if (child.ParentId.HasValue)
                    child.Parent = Parents.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == child.ParentId);
                script.Items.Add(child);
            });

            //Todo: Get sortIndex "sorted" out

            scriptRepository.SaveScript(script);
        }
    }
```

scriptRepository.SaveScript simply sets the script's state to modified and calls SaveChanges().

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what causes this. But I think it may help to add new `ScriptItem` to `script.Items` in stead of setting their owner script, i.e. replace

```
scriptItem.ScriptId = model.ScriptId;
scriptItem.Script = script;
```

by

```
script.Items.Add(scriptItem);
```

Another advantage is that you don't have to change their state manually anymore: the change tracker knows enough when new items are added to a tracked collection. I even wonder if doing this was necessary in your script, because setting `Script` should also have been enough afaik.

Maybe setting `script` *and* `ScriptId` *and* changing the state interfered too much with EF's own logic and put it off track.

Comment: You sir, rock! Although your answer wasn't the exact fix, it lead me down the road to the final fix. Sadly, I cannot upvote your answer since i'm a lowly noob still. Thanks for your response!!!